# SSDT Prevent Synonym Dropping on Publish

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

**Background**

We are using SQL Server Data Tools (SQL Project) that targets SQL Server 2012 which uses DACPAC to publish to our different environments.

**Problem**

Whenever we publish SSDT, the synonyms are being dropped and re-created based on the generated publish script. We want to prevent this from happening since we have a stored procedure that is responsible for setting the correct synonym targets per environment.

```
GO
PRINT N'Dropping [dbo].[MY_SYNONYM]...';
GO
DROP SYNONYM [dbo].[MY_SYNONYM];
GO
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[MY_SYNONYM]...';
GO
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[MY_SYNONYM] FOR [MY_DEFAULT_TARGET];
```

I've tried setting the build action of the synonyms to anything else other than `Build` but it causes a problem with the compiler and results to an unsuccessful build.

Our main goal is to prevent synonym re-creation for synonyms that didn't change targets. We know that we can handle this on our stored procedure by leveraging `sys.synonyms` for comparisons. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT:

I can see the ff on the Advanced Publish Settings but we do not want to enable `Drop objects in target but not in source`. We want the synonyms in the project to not get re-created during publish.

[image: DoNotDropSynonyms]

Comment: Have you tried `SqlPackage.exe /a:publish ... /p:DoNotDropObjectType=Synonyms` or `SqlPackage.exe /a:publish ... /p:ExcludeObjectType=Synonyms` to see if that changes the generated deployment script?
([SqlPackage documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15#publish-parameters-properties-and-sqlcmd-variables))

Comment: @BillJetzer I'll look into this. Is there an equivalent configuration for `/p:DoNotDropObjectType=Synonyms` in Visual Studio? I keep on fiddling with the configurations and haven't found any except for objects found in the target database but are not in the project, for these I can configure what objects not to drop but I have to enable dropping if it doesn't exist in the project first which is not something we would want.

Comment: What if you do a schema compare between project and DB?  Click the gear, then flip to the Object Types tab and uncheck Synonyms, then click "Compare" and then "Generate Script"

Comment: @BillJetzer `/p:ExcludeObjectType=Synonyms` worked, found it under the `Advanced Publish Settings > ignore`. With this I can proceed on changing our SP that creates synonyms with the correct underlying object. Feel free to post it as an answer to this question.

Comment: Make sure that database properties are the same as set in the project advanced properties. Try to align them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Bill Jetzer's recommendation I was able to find the ff in the publish profile:

[image: Exclude object types]

Apparently there's an option `/p:ExcludeObjectType=Synonyms` for [SqlPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15#publish-parameters-properties-and-sqlcmd-variables) if we want to do this using command line.

After ticking the exclude synonyms, in the publish profile the line below was added:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <ExcludeSynonyms>True</ExcludeSynonyms>
</PropertyGroup>
```